# Understanding the difference between setting two nodes equal to each other vs nodes pointing to another node?

Tags: java

Ive been trying to understand the basics of linked lists and I am having trouble interpreting this code:

```
1 private node head = null;
2
3 node prev = null;
4 node curr = head;
5 while (curr != null) {
6   prev = curr;
7   curr = curr.link;

}
```

This small chunk of code is part of code that is looking through a linked list of words. So my question is that for line 6, is the node of prev linking to curr OR is the value of curr equal to prev? Also, Im not sure what is going on in line 7?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to provide more information on this linked list. We don't know what the `node` class looks like. Try creating an actual compilable example instead of pseudocode here.

Comment: First of all, try to follow proper Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what is going on in line 7?

Nothing. `curr = head = null`, so the loop is not going to be executed.

Comment: So what I mean to say, is that when do you actually point to the next node? It isn't done using the "=" operator, right? The "=" just assigns the value of one node to another. Please correct me if Im wrong.

Comment: @AayushK No. `node1 = node2` means that `node1` now is `node2`. If you want to assign the value of one node to another you have to use `node1.value = node2.value`

Comment: So in most cases, when linked lists are being explained, there are diagrams that show nodes as square boxes pointing to each other with arrows. Im trying to visualize what you just explained. So when node1 is now node2, does that mean that a node1 box now has an arrow point to the node2 box? Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @AayushK No. it means that the `node1` box actually **becomes** `node2`. `node1 → node2` means that the `next` node of `node1` is `node2`. `node1 = node2` means that `node1` just became `node2`